# How to access two model attributes in JSP using a loop?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring-mvc, bootstrap and I want to set two attributes and access them simultaneously for a text field in my JSP page, sp that one attribute gives me name and another attribute gives value so in the jsp page I wanted to use the forloop as follow:

```
for(i=0,j=0; i<=len,j<=len; i++,j++)
```

I already tried using this:

```
c:forEach items="${buttonNames,num}" var="buttonName,num"  varStatus="counter">
```

But this results in an error.

Comment: If there is no duplicate in the names, one solution could be to build a Map<String, String> serverside, where the keys are the names and the values the values. Then in JSP, iterating over a map is very simple.

Comment: @user3767879 Why do you need **two** values in your for-loop (i and j) if they both are always the same? And you do know that this: `for(i=0,j=0; i<=len,j<=len; i++,j++)` is no valid syntax?

Comment: no they are not same as in my controller i have string like abc/1 where abc is the name of button i wanna display and 1 is the id whoch i want to use as value of button so that on click of button i get the value 1 and the button gets created dynamically everytime depending on values passed from another jsp page

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:forEach items="${buttonNames}" var="buttonName" varStatus="counter">
    ${num[counter.index]}
</c:forEach>
```

Though better to have a model of a list with buttonName and num.